# Does pytket have an optimization pass that removes gate-inverse pairs & identity rotations & redundant gates and/or merges rotations?

Tags: optimization, pytket

For the following sample circuit I want to reduce the number of gates in pytket:
[image: pytket circuit before]

for example, I know:

- Adjacent Rx gates can be merged
- CZ is self-inverse and cancels itself out because any Hermitian gate is "self-canceling"
- A zero-angle rotation does nothing and the corresponding gate can be removed
- The effect of RZ is eliminated by measurement because we are just rotating around the z-axis which does not change the measurement in the z-basis.

`from pytket import Circuit, OpType`

```
circ = Circuit(3)
circ.Rx(0.92, 0).CX(1, 2).Rx(-0.18, 0)   
circ.CZ(0, 1).Ry(0.11, 2).CZ(0, 1)       
circ.add_gate(OpType.XXPhase, 0.6, [0, 1])
circ.add_gate(OpType.YYPhase, 0, [0, 1])     
circ.add_gate(OpType.ZZPhase, -0.84, [0, 1])
circ.Rx(0.03, 0).Rz(-0.9, 1).Ry(0.13, 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the pytket RemoveRedundancies pass:
[pytket manual](https://cqcl.github.io/tket/pytket/api/passes.html)

```
RemoveRedundancies().apply(circ.measure_all())
```

This should give a total of five reductions in your case! Very nice.

[image: circuit after]